# How do I implement a persistent/universal right bar button item like Music app and Pandora's "Now Playing" buttons?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am writing a streaming music app and I really like the universal "Now Playing" buttons in Music app and Pandora. I am trying to implement them myself. Unfortunately, the methods I tried led to me confusing myself as well as people who tried to help me. Here's what I've tried so far, all of which don't work/work partially:

- Using a `static UIBarButtonItem` in all controllers (works inconsistently, sometimes no segue)
- Adding a button manually to all controllers in Interface Builder (works, but results in a fade-out/fade-in animation when transitioning)
- Creating a view controller which had a `static UIBarButtonItem` from which all controllers subclassed (eliminated the no segue issue from method 1, but still behaves inconsistently)

TL;DR: I don't know how to implement a universal right bar button item. Please tell me how.

[Demo Project](http://cl.ly/1S3N0m3G3k3c) with a blank representation of my hierarchy.

EDIT: Pandora's developer Neil Mix [answered this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/855879/1593651). Exactly the same issue. But I did not understand it. It would be great if someone could explain his method.

Comment: I think you can use this answer, but not sure. similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12391120/1633251

Comment: @DavidH It didn't work.

Comment: You did that on the UIButton, right? Well, if this was me I'd create a minimal demo project with the button in it, and add a small bounty, and for sure someone (or more) will provide an answer. It would be easier to play with a project than just guess at it.

Comment: @DavidH Will surely do that when my question becomes eligible for a bounty. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidH Woah wait, I did not. I tried to set a `UIBarButtonItem` as a static variable and set it as the right bar button. But that results in inconsistent behaviour. The button is set only sometimes.

Comment: If you make it a static item, you can only use it in one view. Instead of doing the above in initWithCoder, did you try moving it to viewDidLoad?

Comment: @DavidH Same thing happens in viewDidLoad. Guess I'll have to wait for the bounty. By the way, my root controller is a tab bar controller, with 5 navigation controllers in it.

Comment: Create a simple demo project, post it to DropBox etc, then add an EDIT: statement to your question to where the project is located. I'll look at it tonight but cannot during the work day.

Comment: Please update the question and specify EXACTLY what you want to have happen to the left button when it or the fixed right button is pressed. I assume that you want it to move as a normal button would. Or is the issue the right button???

Comment: @DavidH I want the left button to behave normally. The issue is with the universal right button. It is universal in every controller, but it fades in and out. I don't want it to fade in or out.

Comment: I am totally perplexed - I ran the demo project on the iPhone 6.1 simulator, and also on my iPhone 4, and there is not any flicker or dimming visible of the right bar button.

Comment: I also can't see any unexpectable behaviour.. it's there on every VC subclassing CustomViewController..

Comment: @DavidH That's because I am now trying to solve it using a static variable. Now, the problem is that the button is set inconsistently. Sometimes it's there, sometimes it's not. I even tried doing it in viewDidLoad as suggested by you, but no go. Sorry if this is becoming confusing.

Comment: @MartinUllrich Try performing all possible combinations of transitions. It sometimes isn't there.

Comment: @DavidH Everything is super-confusing. I am changing the question. Really sorry about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented a solution for you, it uses a singleton `BarButtonManger` which is used by a custom `UINavigationController`-subclass as delegate.
You still have to decide what the target of the button should be (VC navigated to, navigaiton controller, some other singleton / app delegate,..) but this solution should help you: http://cl.ly/3M151o1i3z3O 
Dont forget to change the class of the navigation controllers in your storyboard to CustomNavigationController!

```
//  BarButtonManager.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BarButtonManager : NSObject <UINavigationControllerDelegate>

+ (BarButtonManager*)sharedInstance;

@end


//  BarButtonManager.m
#import "BarButtonManager.h"

@implementation BarButtonManager {
    UIBarButtonItem *_sharedItem;
}

+ (BarButtonManager*)sharedInstance
{
    static BarButtonManager *instance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[BarButtonManager alloc] init];
    });
    return instance;
}


- (UIBarButtonItem*)sharedButtonItem
{
    if (!_sharedItem) { // not thread safe, but let's assume this is only called from UI thread
        UIButton *nowPlayingButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        UIImage *background = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-bar-now-playing-button-silver.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(4.0, 7.5, 5.0, 13.0)];
        UIImage *backgroundPressed = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-bar-now-playing-button-pressed-silver.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(4.0, 7.5, 5.0, 13.0)];

        [nowPlayingButton setBackgroundImage:background forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [nowPlayingButton setBackgroundImage:backgroundPressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

        nowPlayingButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, background.size.width, background.size.height);

        NSMutableParagraphStyle *centre = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
        centre.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        centre.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;


        NSMutableAttributedString *nowPlayingTitle = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Now Playing"];
        [nowPlayingTitle addAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:9.5], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : centre, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]} range:NSMakeRange(0, nowPlayingTitle.length)];


        [nowPlayingButton setAttributedTitle:nowPlayingTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        nowPlayingButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
        nowPlayingButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
        nowPlayingButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
        [nowPlayingButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -3, 0, 5)];

        [nowPlayingButton addTarget:nil action:@selector(nowPlayingPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        _sharedItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:nowPlayingButton];
    }
    return _sharedItem;
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
    UIBarButtonItem *sharedItem = [self sharedButtonItem];
    sharedItem.target = viewController;
    viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = sharedItem;
}

@end


//  CustomNavigationController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomNavigationController : UINavigationController

@end

//  CustomNavigationController.m
#import "CustomNavigationController.h"
#import "BarButtonManager.h"

@implementation CustomNavigationController

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate = [BarButtonManager sharedInstance];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: I want the NowPlayingController to be instantiated from the storyboard and presented when the button is tapped. How do I do that?

Comment: You can still implement the `-nowPlayingPressed` method in CustomViewController. better: implement it in CustomNavigationController and change the `sharedItem.target = viewController` to `sharedItem.target = navigationController`

Comment: I found a better method. Will post it tonight.

Comment: I edited your answer. I will accept this if I don't get a better answer in 36 hours.

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote a blog post about this issue: http://www.codebestowed.com/ios-shared-barbuttonitems

It uses the same strategy as Martin Ullrich but also details how you can set this up in a Storyboard, which requires a bit of a hack. I'll try to summarize here since I know that merely posting links is discouraged in SO.

Basically, the issue is that when you drag a NavigationController into a Storyboard, it doesn't create an editable NavigationBar for you. To get around this, create a ViewController and choose Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller. The NavigationController that gets created via this method will have a NavigationBar that you can drag BarButtonItems to. Link this new controller to your custom subclass of UINavigationController, and then you can create IBOutlets for anything in the nav bar.

So using a combination of this hack and Martin Ullrich's answer will give you the functionality you want + the ability to use the power of Storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

No much pain. You might have a 'player' view controller. And in app delegate create a variable calendar 'universalPlayer'. At the time you create 'player' object, you should assign this on 'universalPlayer'. Then add bar button to your Navigation controller. On the action of bar button you can simply get the player view controller from your AppDelegate. This is a simple solution.